# Javascript animation behaves differently in updated Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

Okay, this one is *really* wierd.

Currently I'm maintaining `rails 3.2.8` application and a couple of days ago I've
noticed that js-animation began to behave differently in updated `Chrome`.

I'm using `bootstrap-modal.js` and `bootstrap-alerts.js` modules from `twitter-bootstrap 1.4`:

— When I'm trying to dismiss alert message, it fades out but the element remains in the code:

```
<div class="alert-message block-message info fade in">
<a href="#" class="close">×</a>
  Lorem ipsum... <a href="http://google.com">A link</a>
</div>
```

so I have the blank space now with the size of dismissed block. And still can click that link other there (blindly).

— When I'm invoking bootstrap modal I'm getting only darkened background overlay, but there's no modal itself. Checked the page source and it has only one new block since the moment event was triggered:

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
```

This happens **only** in `Chrome` (tried `Safari`, `Firefox` — everything's fine) and **only** on *local machine*. There's no such problem on remote server (it has identical code). I also tried to run application in production mode on local machine — same lacks.

And there's no errors or warnings in `Chrome` console.

Tried on 
`Chrome 21.0.1180.89 m` / `22.0.1229.79 m` (Windows 7) 
`Chrome 22.0.1229.91 beta` (OS X 10.6.8)

Found a guy with similar problem but without answer — http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/6-DncVjLZhw (In case you doubt my sanity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea, the update of Chrome is breaking a lot of sites today. The cause is unknown, We can only wait until google developers fix itself. Ok , guess it's happening on all OS systems.

Comment: I have the same issue under Windows 7 — `Chrome 21.0.1180.89 m` & `22.0.1229.79 m`.